# Error while I create a new Npm project it says error while installing dependencies

Tags: npm, dependencies, npm-install, strapi, yarn-lock.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlbI5.jpg)

While creating a npm project I am getting this error.
But when I install yarn.
I don't know how to rerun the program.
Or is it because I installation problem.
Is using the latest version of node an issue.

Can Someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

the strapi supports node version up to 18, you can check it here https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/installation/cli.html#preparing-the-installation

there is flag for npm you can try to use:

```
npx create-strapi-app /appname --ignore-engines
```

However I doubt it would work, the workflow with yarn:

```
yarn create strapi-app /appname
```

If error still persists you can try to open your project with VS code or whatever IDE you use… Open terminal, do:

```
yarn --ignore-engines
yarn build --ignore-engines
yarn develop --ignore-engines
```

If that won’t help, it should give you another, more detailed error message that you should post then here…